# driven animation curves in OpenMaya

Tags: python, maya

I am a bit stuck trying to create driven (unitless) animCurves with OpenMaya

I am in maya 2017, using OpenMaya api 2.0

I am trying to use MFnAnimCurve to create multiple keyframes at the same time. this seems to work when using timed curve types (using MTimeArray as first argument) but it fails when using unitless curves and a MDoubleArray for the first argument..
Am I missing something? should i be using a different type for the first argument?

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om
import maya.api.OpenMayaAnim as oma

graph_modifier = om.MDGModifier()

m_object = om.MFnDependencyNode().create('transform', 'locator1')
node = om.MFnDependencyNode(m_object)

m_plug = node.findPlug(node.attribute('translateX'), True)
out_plug = node.findPlug(node.attribute('translateY'), True)


mfn_anim_curve = oma.MFnAnimCurve()
curve_type = mfn_anim_curve.unitlessAnimCurveTypeForPlug(m_plug)
#curve_type = mfn_anim_curve.timedAnimCurveTypeForPlug(m_plug)


anim_curve_m_object = oma.MFnAnimCurve().create(m_plug, animCurveType=curve_type)
anim_curve = oma.MFnAnimCurve(anim_curve_m_object)

in_plug = anim_curve.findPlug(anim_curve.attribute('input'), True)

graph_modifier.connect(out_plug, in_plug)
graph_modifier.doIt()


in_values = om.MDoubleArray()
out_values = om.MDoubleArray()
for x in range(5):
    in_values.append(float(x))
for x in range(5):
    out_values.append(float(x))

print in_values, out_values

anim_curve.addKey(1.0, 1.0)
anim_curve.addKey(2.0, 2.0)

#This Fails
anim_curve.addKeys(in_values, out_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone pointed out to me, That the documentation for MFnAnimCurve.addKeys() does specify that it only works for kAnimCurveTA, kAnimCurveTL, and kAnimCurveTU. Whereas the type being returned by unitlessAnimCurveTypeForPlug() is kAnimCurveUL